# Why can't I unpack the value in this scala pattern match?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to look up a user using slick (with unicorn) in scala. Here's my code:

```
class UserRepository extends BaseIdRepository[UserId, User, Users](TableQuery[Users]) with IdentityService[User] {

  /**
   * Retrieve the User associated with the given LoginInfo, if any. This method
   * is required by Silhouette.
   * @param loginInfo
   */
  override def retrieve(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[User]] = {
    Future.successful {
      val loginInfoRepository = new LoginInfoRepository
      loginInfoRepository.find(loginInfo) match {
        case Some(retrievedLoginInfo) =>
          val userLoginInfoJunctionRepository = new UserLoginInfoJunctionRepository
          // problem here...
          userLoginInfoJunctionRepository.forB(retrievedLoginInfo.id).firstOption
        case None => None
      }
    }
  }
}

class LoginInfoRepository extends BaseIdRepository[DbLoginInfoId, DbLoginInfo, LoginInfos](TableQuery[LoginInfos]) {
  def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo) = query.filter(
    l =>
      l.providerID == loginInfo.providerID &&
      l.providerKey == loginInfo.providerKey
  ).firstOption
}
```

On the line marked above, intellij prints "type mismatch. Expected DbLoginInfoId, actual Option[DbLoginInfoId]".

Have I got an Option inside an Option, so `retrievedLoginInfo` is actually an `Option[retrievedLoginInfo]`? How can I make this unpack correctly so I can access the ID of the `retrievedLoginInfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `id` on `LoginInfo` is of type `Option[DbLoginInfoId]`, but `forB` takes a `DbLoginInfoId`.

You would need to map over `retrievedLoginInfo.id` to extract the actual value. You can refactor the whole thing with a nicer for-comprehension, like:

```
for {
  retrievedLoginInfo <- loginInfoRepository.find(loginInfo)
  id <- retrievedLoginInfo.id
  userLoginInfoJunctionRepository = new UserLoginInfoJunctionRepository
  res <- userLoginInfoJunctionRepository.forB(id).firstOption
} yield res
```

Comment: You're spot on. I hadn't realised that `id` was itself an Option. And thanks for the tip on the for comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. I think there's some information missing from the question?

Once I filled in enough context around this code, it does compile. The portion of this code that's yours is unaltered:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

package object foo {

  trait LoginInfo {
    def providerID: Any
    def providerKey: Any
  }
  abstract class BaseIdRepository[A, B, C](x: Any)
  trait IdentityService[A] {
    def retrieve(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[User]]
  }
  trait User {
    def id: UserId
  }
  trait UserId
  trait Users
  def TableQuery[A] = ???
  class UserLoginInfoJunctionRepository {
    def forB(x: UserId): QueryResult[User] = ???
  }
  trait DbLoginInfoId
  trait DbLoginInfo
  trait LoginInfos
  trait QueryResult[A] {
    def firstOption: Option[A] = ???
  }
  class Query {
    def filter(f: LoginInfo => Boolean): QueryResult[User] = ???
  }
  val query = new Query()

  // ----

  class UserRepository extends BaseIdRepository[UserId, User, Users](TableQuery[Users]) with IdentityService[User] {

    /**
     * Retrieve the User associated with the given LoginInfo, if any. This method
     * is required by Silhouette.
     * @param loginInfo
     */
    override def retrieve(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[User]] = {
      Future.successful {
        val loginInfoRepository = new LoginInfoRepository
        loginInfoRepository.find(loginInfo) match {
          case Some(retrievedLoginInfo) =>
            val userLoginInfoJunctionRepository = new UserLoginInfoJunctionRepository
            // problem here...
            userLoginInfoJunctionRepository.forB(retrievedLoginInfo.id).firstOption
          case None => None
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class LoginInfoRepository extends BaseIdRepository[DbLoginInfoId, DbLoginInfo, LoginInfos](TableQuery[LoginInfos]) {
    def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo) = query.filter(
      l =>
        l.providerID == loginInfo.providerID &&
          l.providerKey == loginInfo.providerKey
    ).firstOption
  }
}
```

It'd be a lot easier if you could trim the question down to a minimal example.

Comment: Sorry I should have included my models but I thought it was a problem with the syntax of the above. Thanks anyway.